# mysql union of two tables and order the results

Tags: mysql

Excuse my ignorance. I want to take union of the tables invcount2 and reserve1. What is the error in the below code?

```
mysql_query("select distinct Name from exam1sem.invcount2  WHERE Name not in 
(select  Name from exam1sem.invcount2 where Date='$date' AND Time='$time'
 union select  Name from exam1sem.reserve1 where Date='$date' AND 
Time='$time') 

union

select distinct Name from exam1sem.reserve1 WHERE Name not in (select  Name 
from exam1sem.invcount2 where Date='$date' AND Time='$time'
union select  Name from exam1sem.reserve1 where Date='$date' AND 
Time='$time'
)  

order by Avail, TD, NOD
");
```

Comment: I don't think your question is really answerable without your showing us sample input and output data.  By the way, you should look into using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems, You cannot `order by` something which is not present in `select` statement when you are using `distinct` keyword.

You can check this [SQL link](https://paiza.io/projects/f4ejKZXKjUeKFNIyG4aq-A?language=mysql)